# Original version of Thurston's Notes

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a scanned version of the famous Thurston's notes (as it were in ~1980).

I have true difficulties to find the original version ... since the electronic (TeX) version is now everywhere on the web.

Any help appreciated !

Comment: http://www.msri.org/publications/books/gt3m/ is a TeX version of the original notes.

Comment: When I was asked for some documents by Kaplansky, after his death, I asked at the memorial conference at msri, and was snailmailed some documents by a few of his good friends. I suspect the kind of specialized item you want would also need to come from close friends or students of Thurston, and they would need some sort of reason that this is important.... I guess some documents were scanned and sent to me as pdfs; it has been a while.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo : I want the original notes, not the Tex version (as I said)

Comment: @WillJagy : pdfs would sure be great .. I'm surprised this is so hard to find

Comment: I figured, but it is also best to clarify, as one could think you meant the book as opposed to the TeXed notes. I'm not sure I have a copy of the original notes any longer, though, but I'll check.

Comment: Did you try emailing Silvio Levy? (the contact person on MSRI's page for the TeXed version of Thurston's notes)

Comment: @j.c. I didn't ... but if necessary I will

Comment: @j.c. I tried emailing Silvio Levy, without success ... :(

Did anyone find something ?

Comment: I have a typewritten version (not TeX) of "The Geometry and Topology of Three-Manifolds" from 1979. It is spiral bound with hand-drawn figures. Contact me at dradcliffe@gmail.com if you are interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have scanned Dave R's copy of the notes, and placed them at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ThurstonTheGeometryAndTopologyOfThreeManifolds). I believe these are the complete, pre-TeX notes (there is at least one other version that only goes to chapter 9, for example)